# Another ''wifi adapter not found'' problem

Tags: wireless, adapter

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on [Asus VivoBook Max F541NA], after Windows 10 crashed and couldn't even load it.

Everything is working perfectly except the wifi is not found, i can still connect to internet via mobile tethering so please help me fix this situation.

Additional info:

```
$ lspci -knn |grep Net -A3; rfkill list
0: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Wireless info log:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tMP95Kvt3K/

Comment: help please, ploblem persists